# can i send viewmodel and IEnumerable to a view together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

can i have view(in data base : right click on table ----> View ) and a model  into view page together?

i have some fileds on page that wanna send their content to one action result(so i should pass a model to my view , yes?)
 and then the reuslt of action result is view in data base.in fact i have some tds on view pages that wanna fill them by QuerySelect(View In data base).

i did like below . if i click first button i'll get my model null (in [HttpPost])  .
and if click first button my model is null too .

view :

```
       @model Project.Models.MyClass.WholeList


       @using (Html.BeginForm("listPlayer", "Player", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m. PSearch.name, new { @placeholder = "* Enter name" })
           <input type="submit" value="search via name" name="Search" class="btn btn-general" />

                         }

     @model IEnumerable<Project.Models.vw_Players >

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td class="stock">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nam)
            </td>
            <td class="stock">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cost)
            </td>
            <td class="stock">@item.number</td>
            <td class="stock">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.coach)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

               @using (Html.BeginForm("listPlayer", "Player", FormMethod.Post))
                        {


                                  <select name="daystart">
                                    @for (var day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@day">@day</option>
                                    }

                                </select>
                            <select name="monthstart">
                                <option value="01">1</option>
                                <option value="02">2</option>
                                <option value="03">3</option>
                                <option value="04">4</option>
                                <option value="05">5</option>
                                <option value="06">6</option>
                                <option value="07">7</option>
                                <option value="08">8</option>
                                <option value="09">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>

                            </select>
                            <select name="yearstart" >
                                @for (var year = 2013; year <= Myfuc(DateTime.Now); year++)
                                {
                                    <option value="@year">@year</option>
                                }

                            </select>
               <input type="submit" value="seaech" class="btn btn-general" />
                                  }
```

MyClass.cs:

```
       public class Search
       {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int daystart { get; set; }
    public int monthstart { get; set; }
    public int yearstart { get; set; }
    }

    public class WholeList
    {

        public List<Project.Models.vw_ Players > Player { get; set; }
        public Search  PSearch { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller :

```
       [httpGet]
        public ActionResult ListPlayer()
             {

            var db = new ProjectContext();
        var objWhol = new MyClass.WholeList ();
        objWhol.Player = db.vw_Players.ToList();
        return View(objWhol);
        }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ListPlayer ( MyClass.WholeList model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            var myvarible = MyClass.Coachlistpalayer();
             model.Player = myvarible.Where(p => p.nam.ToUpper()).ToList();
            else
            { }
            return View(model);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need general `ViewModel` to iplement this. Something like that

```
public class myViewModel
{
  public List<Project.Models.vw_Players> players {get; set;}
  public MyviewModel Mymodel {get; set;}
}
```

In View:

```
@model Project.Models.myViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.players)
{
//** do somthing
}


@Model.Mymodel.day //** or something else
```

**EDITED.**

You also need change your public `ActionResult ListPlayer()` to return `myViewModel`. Something like that:

```
public ActionResult ListPlayer()
{
  MyviewModel model = new MyviewModel
{
//** define properties here
}
 List<vw_Players> players_ = db.vw_Players.ToList();

var result = new myViewModel
{
players = players_,
Mymodel = model
}

return View(result);

}
```

Comment: thanks . but i should for using Mymodel Like this:  i updeted my question . please see it

Comment: @niki Yes, but you don't need to add Model.Mymodel. View may render only one model. In your case it will be model Project.Models.myViewModel, which contains to models players and Mymodel.

Comment: why it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on  
@foreach (var item in Model.players) ?

Comment: @niki what returns your public ActionResult ListPlayer()? It should return myViewModel

Comment: Andrey.Gubal i'm editing my question , and i 'll show my coding to you . thanks

Comment: Andrey.Gubal can you help me?